Does zinc form any sulfosalts that are not reactive to chromium?
If extremely fine chromium powder is made in a ball mill under inert gas atmosphere, is it possible that adding a sulfosalt of zinc to this process yields a mix of these powders without reaction with chromium?
I'm assuming, this is impossible with most of the sulfosalts of zinc, so I'd like to know which one is the most promising.
At these conditions, a reaction may not have an obvious difference from surface adhesion. Let's say, for clearness, each chromium atom must have another chromium as its nearest neighbor.
